# OpenGL object not rendering correctly?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

The code works with out any errors, but the object displays at white. The IDE I am using is Eclipse.

I tried some debugging and found error #1282 in `UCreateBuffers()`.

```
// header inclusions
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

//GLM math header inclusions
#include <GL/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <GL/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

#define WINDOW_TITLE "Modern OpenGL" // window title macro

// shader program macro
#ifndef GLSL
#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#Version " #Version "\n" #Source
#endif

//variable declarations for shader, window size initialization, buffer and array objects
GLint shaderProgram, WindowWidth = 800, WindowHeight = 600;
GLuint VBO, VAO;

GLfloat cameraSpeed = 0.0005f;

GLchar currentKey; // will store key pressed

//global vector declarations
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f);
glm::vec3 CameraUpY = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glm::vec3 CameraForwardZ = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);


// function prototypes
void UResizeWindow(int, int);
void URenderGraphics(void);
void UCreateShader(void);
void UCreateBuffers(void);
void UKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void UKeyReleased(unsigned char key, int x, int y);

//vertex shader source code
const GLchar * vertexShaderSource = GLSL(330,
        layout (location = 0) in vec3 position; // vertex data from vertex attrib pointer 0
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 color; // color data from vertex attrib pointer 1

        out vec3 mobileColor; // variable to transfer color data to the fragment shader

        // global variables for the transform matrices
         uniform mat4 model;
         uniform mat4 view;
         uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f); //transforms vertices to clip coordinates
    mobileColor = color; // references incoming color data

}
);

// fragment shader source code
const GLchar * fragmentShaderSource = GLSL(330,

        in vec3 mobileColor; // variable to hold incoming color data from vertex shader

        out vec4 gpuColor; // variable to pass color data to the gpu

    void main()
    {
        gpuColor = vec4(mobileColor, 1.0); // sends color data to the gpu for rendering
    }
);


//main program

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
    glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    glutReshapeFunc(UResizeWindow);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

    UCreateShader();

    UCreateBuffers();

    //use the shader program
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //set background color

    glutDisplayFunc(URenderGraphics);

    glutKeyboardFunc(UKeyboard); // detects key press

    glutKeyboardUpFunc(UKeyReleased); // detects key release

    glutMainLoop();

    //destroys buffer objects once used
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

    return 0;
}

//resizes the window
void UResizeWindow(int w, int h)
{
    WindowWidth = w;
    WindowHeight = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
}


// renders graphics
void URenderGraphics(void)
{

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable z-depth

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

     glBindVertexArray(VAO); // Activate the vertex array object before rendering and transforming them

     // Camera Movement Logic
     if(currentKey =='w')
         cameraPosition += cameraSpeed * CameraForwardZ;

     if(currentKey =='s')
         cameraPosition -= cameraSpeed * CameraForwardZ;

     if(currentKey =='a')
         cameraPosition -= glm::normalize(glm::cross(CameraForwardZ, CameraUpY)) * cameraSpeed;

     if(currentKey =='d')
         cameraPosition += glm::normalize(glm::cross(CameraForwardZ, CameraUpY)) * cameraSpeed;


    // transforms the object
     glm::mat4 model;
     model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // place the object at the center of the viewport
     model = glm::rotate(model, 45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0f)); // rotate the object 45 degrees on the x
     model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)); // increase the object size by a scale of 2

     //transform the camera
     glm::mat4 view;
     view = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + CameraForwardZ, CameraUpY);

     //creates a perspective projection
     glm::mat4 projection;
     projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WindowWidth / (GLfloat)WindowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);

     //retrieves and passes transform matrices to the shader program
     GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");
     GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
     GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");

     glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
     glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
     glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));



    glutPostRedisplay();

    //draws the triangles
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glutSwapBuffers(); // flips the back buffer with the front buffer every frame

}


//creates the shader program
void UCreateShader()
{

    //vertex shader
        GLint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); // creates the vertex shader
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL); // attaches the vertex shader to the source code
        glCompileShader(vertexShader); // compiles the vertex shader

        //fragment shader
        GLint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        //shader program
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        // delete the vertex and fragment shaders once linked
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}

void UCreateBuffers()
{

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
                                //positions           //Color
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

                                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

                                -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

                                -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                                -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

                            };


    //generate buffer Ids
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    //activate the vertex array object before binding and setting any VBOs and Vertex Attribute Pointers
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //Activate the VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //set attribute pointer 0 to hold position data
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Enables vertex Attribute

    //set attribute pointer 1 to hold color data
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // enables vertex attribute

    glBindVertexArray(0);// enable the Vao which is good pratice


}


// implements the UKeyboar function
void UKeyboard(unsigned char key, GLint x, GLint y)
{
    switch(key){

    case 'w':
        cout << "You pressed w!" <<endl;
        break;

    case 's':
        cout << "You pressed s!" <<endl;
        break;

    case 'a':
        cout << "You pressed a!" <<endl;
        break;

    case 'd':
        cout << "You pressed d!" <<endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Press a key!" << endl;

    }

}

//implements the UkeyRelease function
void UKeyReleased(unsigned char key, GLint x, GLint y)
{
    cout << "Key released!" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your "Buffer function: …" just shows the same text as the shaders further up. It would be rather important to see how you set up your VAO, however, as I'd suspect the issue might be there (considering that's where your color seems to come from). Also, I don't see you call `glUseProgram()` anywhere.

Comment: @Michael

I made some edits above. Added the Main and change the buffer function. I am glUseProgram(shaderProgram)

Comment: Ok. You mention getting an error 1282 somewhere. Where exactly does that happen? Apart from that, it probably won't hurt to look into [enabling debug output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output) in general.

Comment: It is happening when trying to render the object in a few spots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaders doesn't compile. GLSL is case sensitive. The version qualifier has to be `#version` rather than `#Version`:

<s>`#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#Version " #Version "\n" #Source`</s>

```cpp
#define GLSL(Version, Source) "#version " #Version "\n" #Source
```

---

I recommend to check for compile and link errors and to add an error logging.

Compile errors can be get by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) / [`glGetShaderInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShaderInfoLog.xhtml):

e.g.

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
void UCompileShader( GLuint shader )
{
    glCompileShader( shader );

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if ( status == GL_FALSE )
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Link errors can be get by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) / [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml):

e.g.

```cpp
void ULinkShader( GLuint program )
{
    glLinkProgram( program );

    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if ( status == GL_FALSE )
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout  << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```cpp
//creates the shader program
void UCreateShader()
{
    //vertex shader
    GLint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL); 
    UCompileShader(vertexShader); // compiles the vertex shader

    //fragment shader
    GLint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    UCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    //shader program
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    ULinkShader(shaderProgram);

    // delete the vertex and fragment shaders once linked
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
}
```

Comment: Rabbid thank you. Everything is working as it should. What is the reason for the IDE not to throw an error or warning. For the capitalized word?

Comment: @solidsandwich The driver generates an error. But you've to get the errors by `glGetProgramiv`. An option would be to enable [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output).